# Active/passive : The thief stole my cloak as I was asleep in the waiting room

Tags: passive-voice, exam-questions, active-voice

> The thief stole my cloak as I was asleep in the waiting room.

Which is the better option to change voice of the above given sentence from the below given two options :

A) My cloak was stolen as I was asleep in the waiting room.

Or

B) As I was asleep in the waiting room, my cloak was stolen.

I had four options with me out of which I managed to rule out two options but I am confused between these two options, my book has **A** as answer but my question is why *A* why not *B* ? Is there any difference in meaning ? Why *A* is better ?

Comment: I don't think your "book" is a reliable guide to idiomatic English. Google Books has [just one written instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stolen+as+I+was+asleep%22) of *stolen as I was asleep*, and that's from a guide to English published by a *German* company. But there are an estimated 63 written instances of [*stolen **while** I was asleep*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stolen+while+I+was+asleep%22). I've no idea what aspect of English your book is trying to teach you (difference between ***as = while*** and ***as = because***?), but it's a terrible example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no rule in English syntax which marks A) as preferable to B), and I know of no such rule in any canon of style. You will have to read your book more closely to see whether it offers any applicable "rule". If it does, you may ask here whether the "rule" is valid; but as the question stands it basically asks us to read the author's mind, and I think that makes it  unanswerable.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't understand why you think the question should be closed. As far as I can tell, it seems to be a valid question where the answer is "there is no apparent reason to favour either". Finding out whether/why their book is right/wrong is surely still on-topic? That said, specifying the source and any further context would probably be helpful...

Comment: In  my question  I wasn't asking about my book nor I said that my book is correct or its a rule or anything like that, I just mentioned that my book preferred option A instead of B and my question was, although I have clearly mentioned in thread itself but writing again, **is there any difference in meaning in the two given options**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: **as** is fine to my (AmE) ear.  Compare Faulkner's *As I Lay Dying*,  or the British traditional folksong "One night as I lay in my bed".  **as I slept** is plenty well attested.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The book may be a terrible book, as you say (or it could be a good book that happens to have one bad question). In any event, I think the question is valid and well-presented. Perhaps someone could say whether the answer might change if the samples used "while" or "because" in place of "as."

Comment: Before we heap calumny upon some wretch of an author, are you sure this question comes from an actual _book?_ It looks to me as if it comes from a 2013 examination for the post of Assistant Sub Inspector for the Delhi Central Armed Police Forces.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: *One night as I lay in my bed* is a pretty dated / stylised / poetic construction, and I don't see how you can argue with the 63:1 ratio in my earlier comment. But if you insist, I'll just point out that according to NGrams, the most common word before *while I was asleep* is in fact ***me***. So I checked Google Books to find [about 4320 hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22me+while+I+was+asleep%22) for *me while I was asleep*, but only [**one**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22me+as+I+was+asleep%22) instance of *me as I was asleep*. I rest my case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: **As** may be used less often than **while** under certain circumstances, but at least as far as AmE is concerned (and I would venture to say, BrE), the word **as** in its temporal sense is not "dated / stylised / poetic". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+they+were+walking%2C+while+they+were+walking&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20they%20were%20walking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhile%20they%20were%20walking%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I suggest there are subtle aspects to the usage. *We bring you the news **as** it happens* is far more natural than ***while** it happens* - but as I think I've already proved, a sentence such as *It happened **as** I was asleep* is a complete non-starter compared to ***...while** I was asleep*. Perhaps it turns on a distinction between ***during** [some time-period]* and ***at the same time as** [some activity]*. But it seems to me whatever governs this must be "real", since most native speakers would *almost always* make the same choices in many such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think anything has been proved with the Google search. Do you honestly think a Google Books search as specific as ***stolen** as I was asleep* is going to tell you much?   IMO, **as** (temporal) and **was asleep** are in different registers.  So you would find/hear **as I slept** and **as I was sleeping** but not **as I was asleep**.  And so there may be some common ground here, but I wouldn't go as far as to say that **as** is poetic or dated or stylised, as you have done.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I never actually claimed that "temporal **as**" is poetic/dated as a general principle. What I said originally was in respect of *OP's specific cited context*, where I really do think the evidence (and my own gut feel for use of English) points to a clear-cut preference. And I kinda doubt there's any meaningful difference in "register" between ***asleep*** and ***sleeping***, if that's what you were implying. But even if there were, this would hardly be relevant to contexts like *[something happened to] me **while** I was away* (where no-one would say ***...as** I was away*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree with your textbook. Both A and B are equally grammatical and mean the same thing.

If I had to force a difference (only bother with this if you are interested since it's of such limited value), I'd say that **A is about your cloak** that was stolen and **B is about what happened while you were asleep**. This difference is really only present in the spoken language and the actual word order is not as relevant as the direction of the conversation. In written English, sentences like B are more common than in spoken English and the distinction (however little it had in the first place) is no longer present.

Comment: one reason why we might avoid using as is because it can be ambiguous. Was the cloak stolen because you were asleep, or while you were asleep? This question is a good illustration: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31625/9161

Answer (score 1):

Most fluent speakers would use "while" rather than "as". With that change, either version is equally good and valid: "My cloak was stolen while I was asleep", or "While I was asleep, my cloak was stolen."

"As" can also mean "because". For example, "As you were here first, you can choose whatever seat you want." Because of this, (b) creates the possible ambiguity that the writer may mean, "While I was asleep ..." or "Because I was asleep ...". That's the only reason I can think of to prefer (a).